# How to center a small canvas on a larger jframe

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

> Like the title says, i am looking to center a 800x600 canvas on a 1920x1080 screen
>   [image]
>   I want the canvas to be centered in the JFrame

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7045103465799258651L;
    Dimension d;


    public Window(int w, int h, String title,Launcher launch){
        setTitle(title);

        d = new Dimension(w,h);
        setMinimumSize(d);
        setMaximumSize(d);
        setPreferredSize(d);

        setVisible(true);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        pack();

        setFocusable(true);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        add(launch);
        launch.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: is `launch` the JPanel? If so, try adding it before your call to pack.

Comment: No launch is the canvas

Comment: Same thing here, then. Try adding it before your call to `pack()`.

Comment: setLayout ( new BorderLayout() );
add( launch, BorderLayout.CENTER );

Comment: You could also add launch to the content pane, as it already has a `BorderLayout` by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

- Give your container a GridBagLayout
- Add your component, your drawing JPanel (not Canvas), to the container without use of GridBagConstraints. It will add it to the container by default in a centered position.
- If you use BorderLayout like many are telling you, your component will *fill* the container, which does not seem to be what you're aiming for here.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestCenterLayout extends JPanel{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private static final int PREF_W = 800;
   private static final int PREF_H = 600;
   private static final Color BACKGROUND = Color.pink;

   public TestCenterLayout() {
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("800 x 600 Panel"));
      setBackground(BACKGROUND);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Center Layout");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      frame.getContentPane().add(new TestCenterLayout());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```